# HP DL180 G6: where is temp sensor #21

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, ilo, physical-environment

With the warmer summer days starting to hit, my server is increasingly going into thermal protection shutdown due to temp sensor #21 reaching critical level (58*C), as reported in ILO.

The fans are all running fine but unfortunately, the server is not in a climate controlled room and there isn't much I can do about the ambient temperature. However, if I know where sensor #21 is, I can try to improve the airflow around that area. And if it's an IC, I can add/beef up the heatsink to improve cooling.

Does anybody know where that sensor is?

Edit:

Levels at night time:

```
                 Location        Status  Reading  Thresholds  
Temp 1:          System Zone     Ok      15C      Caution: 42C; Critical:47C  
Temp 2 (CPU 1):  System 1        Ok      40C      Caution: 82C; Critical:83C  
Temp 3 (CPU 2):  System 2        Ok      40C      Caution: 82C; Critical:83C  
Temp 4:          Memory Zone     Ok      37C      Caution: 87C; Critical:92C  
Temp 5:          Memory Zone     Ok      41C      Caution: 87C; Critical:92C  
Temp 6:          System Zone     n/a     n/a      Caution: 99C; Critical:99C  
Temp 7:          System Zone     n/a     n/a      Caution: 99C; Critical:99C  
Temp 8 (MemB0):  Memory Zone     Ok      34C      Caution: 62C; Critical:67C  
Temp 9 (MemB0):  Memory Zone     Ok      34C      Caution: 61C; Critical:66C  
Temp 10 (MemB0): Memory Zone     Ok      33C      Caution: 61C; Critical:66C  
Temp 12 (MemB1): Memory Zone     Ok      38C      Caution: 66C; Critical:71C  
Temp 13 (MemB1): Memory Zone     Ok      39C      Caution: 65C; Critical:70C  
Temp 14 (MemB1): Memory Zone     Ok      38C      Caution: 70C; Critical:75C  
Temp 15:         System Zone     Ok      40C      Caution: 57C; Critical:62C  
Temp 16:         System Zone     Ok      33C      Caution: 50C; Critical:55C  
Temp 17:         System Zone     Ok      35C      Caution: 58C; Critical:63C  
Temp 18:         System Zone     Ok      45C      Caution: 110C; Critical:115C  
Temp 19:         System Zone     Ok      41C      Caution: 57C; Critical:62C  
Temp 20:         System Zone     Ok      42C      Caution: 53C; Critical:58C  
Temp 21:         System Zone     Ok      49C      Caution: 53C; Critical:58C  
Temp 22 (PCIR):  I/O Board Zone  n/a     n/a      Caution: 99C; Critical:99C  
Temp 23 (PCIR):  I/O Board Zone  n/a     n/a      Caution: 99C; Critical:99C  
Temp 24 (PCIR):  I/O Board Zone  n/a     n/a      Caution: 99C; Critical:99C  
Temp 25 (PCIR):  I/O Board Zone  n/a     n/a      Caution: 99C; Critical:99C  
Temp 26:         Storage Zone    Ok      0C       Caution: 99C; Critical:99C  
Temp 27:         Storage Zone    Ok      0C       Caution: 99C; Critical:99C  
Temp 28:         Storage Zone    Ok      0C       Caution: 99C; Critical:99C  
Temp 29:         Storage Zone    Ok      0C       Caution: 99C; Critical:99C  
Temp 30:         Storage Zone    Ok      0C       Caution: 99C; Critical:99C  
Temp 31:         Storage Zone    Ok      0C       Caution: 99C; Critical:99C
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you have a DL180 G6? Our sensor count is different and the thresholds are not the same. What is the disk layout and RAID controller setup in this server?

Comment: It's a DL180 G6 SE326M1 with 25xSSF disks and a P812

Comment: A P812 in that server doesn't quite make sense unless you're running external storage as well. I'd be using a P410. In either case, it's still a supported configuration. I'd ensure that your firmware is up-to-date on the system BIOS and ILO. If no change, I'd call HP.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Yes, the P812 is driving an MSA60 with 3TB SATA drives and the internal SFFs. I last ran HP SUM in March but I'll give it another go.

Comment: That's pretty recent. Call HP or see if you have a BIOS option for "increased cooling" because of the P812's presence. Can you also output `hplog -f` ?

Answer (score 2):

Does it matter which sensor #21 is? What would you actually *do* about it?

Can you check your ambient temperature? What can you control about your environment to keep that within a reasonable range? Are you absolutely *sure* you don't have a failed fan?

--edit--

It makes sense to ensure the firmware of ALL of your components is up-to-date. For you, that means your system BIOS, ILO, RAID controller, NIC, backplane and disks. These can all be covered by the [HP Support Pack for ProLiant bootable DVD](http://h17007.www1.hp.com/us/en/enterprise/servers/products/service_pack/spp/index.aspx). Please download and run.

Check the internal health LED on the server. If you're running a supported version of Linux or Windows, install the HP management agents and check the output of `hplog -t` to get temperature sensor information. The output of a standard DL180 G6 config looks like the following. Correlate your results with mine:

*note: there are four fans in this system*

```
# hplog -f
ID     TYPE        LOCATION      STATUS  REDUNDANT FAN SPEED
 1  Var. Speed   System Board    Normal     N/A     Normal   ( 55)
 2  Var. Speed   System Board    Normal     N/A     Normal   ( 59)
 3  Var. Speed   System Board    Normal     N/A     Normal   ( 63)
 4  Var. Speed   System Board    Normal     N/A     Normal   ( 53)
```

---

```
# hplog -t
ID     TYPE        LOCATION      STATUS    CURRENT  THRESHOLD
 1  Basic Sensor Mem. Brd. (1)  Normal    78F/ 26C 188F/ 87C
 2  Basic Sensor Mem. Brd. (1)  Normal    78F/ 26C 188F/ 87C
 3  Basic Sensor Mem. Brd. (1)  Normal    82F/ 28C 188F/ 87C
 4  Basic Sensor Mem. Brd. (1)  Absent   ---F/---C ---F/---C
 5  Basic Sensor Mem. Brd. (1)  Normal    80F/ 27C 188F/ 87C
 6  Basic Sensor Mem. Brd. (1)  Absent   ---F/---C ---F/---C
 7  Basic Sensor Mem. Brd. (1)  Normal   104F/ 40C 203F/ 95C
 8  Basic Sensor Mem. Brd. (2)  Absent   ---F/---C ---F/---C
 9  Basic Sensor Mem. Brd. (2)  Absent   ---F/---C ---F/---C
10  Basic Sensor Mem. Brd. (2)  Absent   ---F/---C ---F/---C
11  Basic Sensor Mem. Brd. (2)  Absent   ---F/---C ---F/---C
12  Basic Sensor Mem. Brd. (2)  Absent   ---F/---C ---F/---C
13  Basic Sensor Mem. Brd. (2)  Absent   ---F/---C ---F/---C
14  Basic Sensor Mem. Brd. (2)  Absent   ---F/---C ---F/---C
15  Basic Sensor System Board    Absent   ---F/---C ---F/---C
16  Basic Sensor System Board    Absent   ---F/---C ---F/---C
17  Basic Sensor Ambient         Normal    71F/ 22C 140F/ 60C
18  Basic Sensor Ambient         Normal    80F/ 27C 158F/ 70C
19  Basic Sensor System Board    Normal    68F/ 20C 233F/112C
20  Basic Sensor System Board    Normal    86F/ 30C 174F/ 79C
21  Basic Sensor System Board    Normal    73F/ 23C 140F/ 60C
22  Basic Sensor System Board    Normal    75F/ 24C 143F/ 62C
23  Basic Sensor System Board    Normal    75F/ 24C 143F/ 62C
24  Basic Sensor System Board    Normal    71F/ 22C 143F/ 62C
25  Basic Sensor System Board    Normal    71F/ 22C 172F/ 78C
26  Basic Sensor System Board    Normal    71F/ 22C 172F/ 78C
27  Basic Sensor System Board    Normal    71F/ 22C 172F/ 78C
28  Basic Sensor System Board    Normal    77F/ 25C 185F/ 85C
29  Basic Sensor System Board    Normal    75F/ 24C 185F/ 85C
30  Basic Sensor System Board    Normal    77F/ 25C 185F/ 85C
31  Basic Sensor System Board    Normal    84F/ 29C 159F/ 71C
32  Basic Sensor System Board    Normal    86F/ 30C 176F/ 80C
33  Basic Sensor System Board    Normal    68F/ 20C 140F/ 60C
34  Basic Sensor System Board    Normal    68F/ 20C 140F/ 60C
35  Basic Sensor System Board    Normal   107F/ 42C 230F/110C
```

Comment: Well, what he CAN do is make sure that the sensor reading makes sense. I have 2 SuperMicro cases, identical, one above the other. In one I get sensor temperature warnings on the SAS backplane, the other is somehow 20 degree less in temperature. We checked airflow and room temperature multiple times - this ONE sensor is off. WAY off.